# Сделать блок div по центру родительского блока, а содержимое блока div выровнять по правому краю

Tags: html, css

Необходимо расположить блок `div` горизонтально по центру родительского блока, а содержимое блока `div` должно горизонтально располагаться по правому краю блока.

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">                 
    <div class="child">
      <div class="text-right">
        text 1
      </div>
      <div class="text-right">                                
        text 2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Text 1 и Text 2 должны быть посредине и на разных строках. Не могу понять что добавить надо.

Comment: и в чём суть проблемы? ТЗ вижу, код вижу, выводов из того, чем не подходит код под ТЗ не вижу

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Центрирование текста в блоке фиксированной ширины

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">                 
    <div class="child">
      <div class="text">
        text 1
      </div>
      <div class="text">                                
        text 2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Центрирование текста с помощью padding

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">                 
    <div class="child">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor
      </div>
      <div class="text">                                
        Sit amet
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Поскольку автор путается в заголовке вопроса и в комментариях, что ему нужно,
вот альтернативное решение для другой описанной им проблемы:

---

#### Центрирование блока фиксированной ширины внутри родителя

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">                 
    <div class="child">
      <div class="text">
        text 1
      </div>
      <div class="text">                                
        text 2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Центрирование блока динамической ширины внутри родителя

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">                 
    <div class="child">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor
      </div>
      <div class="text">                                
        Sit amet
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот то, что надо "Центрирование блока динамической ширины внутри родителя"

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так:

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-right {
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">                 
    <div class="child">
      <div class="text-right">
        text 1
      </div>
      <div class="text-right">                                
        text 2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не то, так как Text 1 и Text 2 должны быть посредине и на разных строках

Comment: Поправила. А вообще сразу нужно в вопросе писать, что у вас конкретно не получается)